# Best Way to Implement Basic Content Manager Permissions

Tags: 2sxc

We've added a role to DNN named, "Content Manager." Almost all the site's content is in 2sxc Content app stuff; Basic Content, Links, Locations, etc. What is the most efficient way to get DNN and 2sxc setup so that these users can only Edit the content. Not change the template (View) or get in to DNN's module or page settings or anything else. Most of our efforts so far either involve a lot of setup work and module permission changes - or - if we stick close to the defaults, we give these users too many options when logged in. Basically we want them to only see the blue circle edit pencil button and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found this by accident, but it seems to work! Perhaps @iJungleBoy has some additional feedback.

Get the RoleID from the database for the role you created for Content Editors. Then, in your 2SXC app, go to the apps Administration page, click App in the top toolbar, click the icon next to App Permissions, add a new permission with the ID of the role in the Identity field, leave the condition unset, and choose from the Grant options that meets your need. The entry for "Edit (Create, Read, Update, Delete)" may be what you are looking for.

If that doesn't work, you may need to manage the App Permissions for all 2sxc apps. You can follow [this link](https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/wiki/concept-permissions) for background on it. Basically you need to put the page in Edit mode and then on the gear icon select Apps Management. On that screen, click the Features button on the toolbar. Click Manage Features, and then enable the one entitled "Permission by Group / Role".

For more background on permissions, check [here](https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/wiki/concept-permissions).

Hope that helps get you on a good path.